# Query returns result with small size that is not my intention in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using rest api to query the result from `ElasticSearch`.

Below is the API query string.

```
GET /..../_search
{
"size":0,
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
             "time_zone": "+09:00",        
              "gte": "2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z", 
              "lt": "2023-01-24T03:03:00.000Z" } } },
          {
                      "term" : {
                        "serviceid.keyword" : {
                          "value" : "430011397"
                        }
                      }
                    }
        ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_day": {
      "auto_date_histogram": {
        "field":     "@timestamp",
        "minimum_interval":"minute"
      },
          "aggs": {
            "agg-type": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "nxlogtype.keyword",
                "size": 100000
              },
              "aggs": {
                      "my-sub-agg-name": {
                        "avg": {
                          "field": "size"
                        }
                      }
                }
              }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I specified the time range about three hours in `gte` and `lt` field.
However, the result returns only 6 buckets which have 30 minute intervals.
I expected that many buckets will be returned with one minute interval during the timestamp I specified, but the result is always same even though I changed the time range as more extended one.

Since I am quite new to elastic search, I am not familiar with query usage.
How to resolve my issue?

Comment: was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

> I expected that many buckets will be returned with one minute interval during the timestamp I specified

What you're describing seems to be the `date_histogram` aggregation ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html)), while you're using the `auto_date_histogram`, where the minimum_interval property doesn't do what you're expecting it to do ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-autodatehistogram-aggregation.html#_minimum_interval_parameter))